# How to get Python support on MS Windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, vimscript-python

I've installed the latest version of Vim to date (8.0) for Windows. But the version of Vim I've got does not have Python support. I've downloaded the .exe version directly from [vim.org](http://www.vim.org).

```
echo has('python') 
" returns 0.
```

If I remember correctly, Vim used to come with Python support in the default build. Is this no longer true?

Do I have to compile Vim with Python support myself (and how to do that on MS Windows) or is there another way?

Comment: NOTE: I have Python installed on my computer.

Answer (score 10):

You need to install Python yourself on Windows.

If you type `:version`, you should see `+python/dyn` and `+python3/dyn`.  On Windows, this means that Vim is compiled to dynamically load the Python DLL.  You can read about this in [`:h python-dynamic`](https://vimhelp.org/if_pyth.txt.html#python-dynamic).  Depending on the versions you install, you may want to look at [`:h pythondll`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27pythondll%27) and [`:h pythonthreedll`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27pythonthreedll%27).

If you install Python 3, keep in mind that you will need to verify it with `:echo has('python3')`.  Additionally, if you want to install both Python 2 and 3, you will want to read [`:h has-python`](https://vimhelp.org/if_pyth.txt.html#has-python).

Comment: Also be sure to use a 32-bit python with a 32-bit vim, or use a 64-bit version of both. If you mix them, vim will not be able to load the dll.