# Getting Python support for gVim 8.1 (Windows 10)

Tags: microsoft-windows, plugin-you-complete-me, plugin-python-mode

As an extension (follow-up question) of the answer [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11008/20750):

> If you type `:version`, you should see `+python/dyn` and `+python3/dyn`. On Windows, this means that Vim is compiled to dynamically load the Python DLL. You can read about this in `:h python-dyanmic`. Depending on the versions you install, you may want to look at `:h pythondll` and `:h pythonthreedll`
>
> If you install Python 3, keep in mind that you will need to verify it with `:echo has('python3')`. Additionally, if you want to install both Python 2 and 3, you will want to read `:h has-python`.

I've checked the version settings and ensured the existence of both `+python/dyn` and `+python3/dyn`. I have the latest distribution of Python 3 (which, at this time, is 3.7.2), and have installed a 32-bit version of it so that it's compatible to my 32-bit gVim 8.1, as per the comment in the quoted answer:

> Also be sure to use a 32-bit python with a 32-bit vim, or use a 64-bit version of both. If you mix them, vim will not be able to load the `dll`.

However, even after several reboots and re-installations, the command `:echo has('python3')` still returns `0`. How can I make sure that Python 3 is supported on Vim?

I just wanted to use that YCM plugin...

Comment: What's the output of `:set pythonthreedll?`?

Comment: It's `=python36.dll`.

Comment: I guess the dll in 3.7.2 is `python37.dll`. Try `set pythonthreedll=python37.dll`. If that doesn't work use the full path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With dynamic python, the name of the python DLL (or shared object on Unix) is defined at compile time. In your case it is `python36.dll`. As you now want to use a different python version, this name needs to be changed.

For this Vim has the option `pythonthreedll` (and `pythondll` for python2). Set it to the name of DLL you want to load.

Add the following to your `vimrc`:

```
set pythonthreedll=python37.dll
```

If this doesn't work you can also set the full path to that library. In that case you might also need to set `pythonthreehome`:

```
set pythonthreedll=c:\path\to\python\python37.dll
set pythonthreehome=c:\path\to\python
```

AFAIK this second way is needed, when python was not installed but just unpacked. In that case, the DLL is not registered to Windows and hence can't be found by name.